# How to stop an auto creation of folder and tailwindcss file every time i save?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, terminal, tailwind-css

Hi i tried to install TailwindCSS to a project for a test, but after i trashed every file in the bin because i don't wanted Tailwind anymore. Now every time i save files in that project it create automatically a folder with a css file that contain the starter code of Tailwind.. how to fix that?

I tried to delete the file every time it's created but after a save, it re-appear. It's like there's a command in the terminal which make that.

Comment: How exactly did you install Tailwind and how did you remove it? Because if you installed the package with e.g. `npm install` and then you removed some files from the `node_modules` folder, the files are likely to come back sooner or later.

Comment: installed with the CLI guide on their site. Maybe is fault of a "--watch" command i used for creating the file that continue to be created at every saving? For the "how did you remove it" like i said: i just trashed the file